# Bootstrap glyphicon icon not showing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons

The glyphicon icon on all buttons - bootstrap does not show up in safari or chrom

I couldn't fix it. Please help!

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<a class="btn btn-primary" href="ClockProject/index.html" 
  target="_blank">View Project 
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you made sure the fonts have been included in the project? Viewing the console for your site, you have errors in which it failed to load the glyphicons (font pack).

```
bootstrap/
├── css/
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── bootstrap.css.map
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
├── js/
│   ├── bootstrap.js
│   └── bootstrap.min.js
└── fonts/
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
    └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

Comment: I didn't know have to include the fonts. Thank you. I will add it now.

Comment: You can download from here the fonts: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/tree/master/assets/fonts/bootstrap

Comment: fonts file is important,
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/tree/master/assets/fonts/bootstrap
for download open above link, click each link with ctrl key. only glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg file, you have to save with right click.